# Importing multiple JSON files to PowerBI - What format does it want?

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery

I've been able to successfully import of a single JSON file to Power BI - but am struggling to find out how to appease the 'Folder' import data source with the same data schema across multiple files.

The error is always some variation on `We found extra characters at the end of JSON input` - Usually the opening character of the 2nd file. E.g.:

[image: Power BI error]

I assume there's some spec to how it expects the data to be split across files - but I really can't figure out what it wants. Help?

*For example:*

I've been able to import a single file (in JSON-array format) like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Person1",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Person2",
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

When I create a 2nd file with the same schema (and slightly varied data) - I get the error.

I tried moving it out to a named param - but still the same issue.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Person1",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Person2",
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: It's from expanding the Binary content:

[image]

So I assume it's from either the of the last 2 steps:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use the combine binaries button here. Instead, you can add a custom column with the custom formula `Json.Document([Content])`.

Comment: Thanks - could you give a little more context on what the `[Context]` part would look like?

Comment: [Content] is the column in the table you got by using From Folder. Content contains the actual content of the file, which Json.Document will turn into a record or list of records. The step's full formula will be something like `Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Json.Document([Content]))`.